# Prove that$ f(x)=\ln(x)$, where $ x>0$ is of exponential order.

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Prove that$ f(x)=\ln(x)$, where $ x>0$ is of exponential order.

I know that if there exists a constant a and positive constants $t_0$ and $M$ such that $|f(t)| \leq M e^{at}$ at for all $t > t_0$ at which f(t) is defined then the function f is said to be of exponential order.

I also know that we are dealing with Laplace integrals in this section.

What I do not know is how to use this information to provide a proof.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** You may easily prove
$$
0\leq\ln t \leq t \leq e^t,\qquad t\geq1
$$ giving
$$|f(t)| \leq e^{t},\qquad t\geq1.$$

Comment: But $t$ needs to be $>0,$ not $1$.

Comment: @chriskinda ,in that case $lnt$ becomes -ve.